# jQuery not working in chrome but working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome, firefox

I can't use jQuery in Chrome but it works in Firefox. What is the problem here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
  $('.test').click(function () {
    console.log('test');
  });
});
```

It does log "ready" but it doesn't log "test". In firefox it works..

CDN i use:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Element:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success test">Test</button>
```

Comment: So where is the element with class `test`?

Comment: I just try your code and it works in Chrome 57.0 with a simple `div` with the class `.test`.

Comment: @Arg0n I've editted my post.

Comment: @YoannFleuryDev So, is my Google Chrome broken or something? It's just weird..

Comment: @itvba Must be something else going on with your code I think. Is my snippet below really not working for you?

Comment: @itvba That's probably a plugin, Chrome doesn't seem to have a bug like that. Did you try in an incognito window with all the plugins disabled?

Comment: I think the issue is with chrome 61*. I have the same problem, at first I thought it has to do with codeigniter and i changed to Laravel. Now I discover this happen each time i add jQuery to my app and my chrome recently update to 61*. Same code on chrome in my phone displayed as it should

Answer (score 0):

Works in Chrome, nothing to see here ppl.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log( "ready!" );
  $('.test').click(function () {
    console.log('test');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success test">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by just reinstalling mac OSX. My MacBook was a bit buggy anyway and this solved the problem. Thanks for everyone who was thinking with me and sorry i've posted a post like this.